# Display Woocommerce Checkout fields (billing, payment, ...) on custom pages, sections etc. via Shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to customize the checkout process in woocommerce and change it into a multi step layout.
My idea was to create shortcodes for the different elements in the checkout so that I could display them wherever I want:

1. Shortcode User login or Registration
2. Shortcode for billing-fields + Coupon field
3. Shortcode for Shipping-fields
4. Shortcode for Payment + Order Review and buy-botton

My Problem is, I got no coding experience... So I hope that anybody could help me out with this?

I did not try something cause i do not know how to solve the problem...

Comment: Hire someone since will require heavy understanding of Woo system.